# Null-safe way to use Router in next.js with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

next.js advices the following pattern to access to the route params:

```
const Page = withRouter((props) => (
  <p>{props.router.query.title}</p>
))
```

Now the problem is that in TypeScript the code above would show an error because `router` and `query` could be undefined. It has to be rewritten either as

`props.router!.query!.title`

or as

`props.router && props.router.query && props.router.query.title`

both ways are bad in my opinion. In the first one we just forcing compiler to ignore the error and in other bloat the code with unnecessary noise.

Is there a better way to access the route params?

Comment: Are you sure you have everything correctly installed? I have all the required types within the next package and therefore no problems with accessing query strings. When navigating withRouter import it gets me to with-router.d.ts file, can you try to navigate and confirm you end up in same file?

Comment: Which version of Next.js are you using?

Comment: is using `lodash` out of question? If not you can just `_.get(props, "router.query.title");`

Comment: do `const router = useRouter();` instead

Answer (score 2):

There is a [proposal for optional chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) in JavaScript, but seems like it'll take a while before it's finalized.

You're correct on avoiding `props.router!.query!.title` to ignore the typecheck errors. You would have to conditionally check for the existing properties as you suggested: `props.router && props.router.query && props.router.query.title`

I usually create a helper function to accept an object and fetch a nested property from it. Or better you can use an existing library such as [lodash get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#get):

```js
import get from 'lodash/get'

...
const title = get(props, ['router', 'query', 'title'])
...
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an [operator called optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.` that let's you read the value from a object chain without having to validate that each reference is valid. Instead of causing an error it will return undefined.

So you can do:

```
const Page = withRouter((props) => (
    <p>{props.router?.query?.title}</p>
))
```